# Creating PowerLaw Data

Tags: probability-or-statistics

```
qpowerlaw[p_, alpha_, xmin_, lower_, logp_] := {
    lower = True;
    logp = False;
    If[lower == False, p = -1 - p];
    If[logp, -Exp[p]];
    xmin*(1 - p)^(-1/(alpha - 1));
}

rpowerlaw[n_, xmin_, alpha_] := { 
    powList = Table[qpowerlaw[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]], {i,0, n}]; 
}
```

I am trying to use these two functions to properly write these lines of code in R, but I can't figure out how quite to do it.

Here is the code in R:

```
qpowerlaw <- function(p, alpha=2, xmin=1, lower.tail=T, log.p = F) {
     if (!lower.tail)
         p <- 1-p
     if (log.p)
         p <- exp(p)
     xmin * ((1 - p) ^ (-1 / (alpha - 1)))
}
rpowerlaw <- function(n, alpha=2, xmin=1) {
     qpowerlaw(runif(n, 0, 1), alpha, xmin)
```

}

I want to be able to test alpha = 1.8 and xmin = 10, but when I run my code.  I am getting results in `powlist` that are less than one, which can not be right.  I tried to use `ParetoDistribution` to properly create the data, but I could not produce the kind of results i wanted (the alpha values between the ParetoDistribution and PowerLaw are very different).  I also tried `PowerDistribution`, which lacks the xmin parameter, so I couldn't use that function either.  If anyone knows, something I could try or any errors in my code.  It would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling your function? One obvious problem I see is that `qpowerlaw[]` requires 5 variables, but in `rpowerlaw[]` you are calling it with just one.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that, and it fixed up the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the typos in your code.  (Sometimes you are translating "<-" in *R* to "=-" in *Mathematica* when it should translate just to "=".)  Also, the R code results in a vector of length `n` rather than `n+1` which is what you get from `{i,0,n}`.

Does the following do what you want?

```
qpowerlaw[p_, alpha_: 2, xmin_: 1, lower_: True, logp_: False] := {
  If[! lower, p = 1 - p];
  If[logp, p = Exp[p]];
  xmin*(1 - p)^(-1/(alpha - 1))}

rpowerlaw[n_, alpha_: 2, xmin_: 1] :=
  Table[qpowerlaw[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}]], alpha, xmin][[1]], {i, n}]

rpowerlaw[12, 2, 10]
(* {322.81124530346244`,48.06374170498156`,18.70766795287194`,18.129813319193655`,
10.55503923120391`,20.328561054608628`,10.664461248009385`,51.58041120231046`,
10.103780695831814`,24.197428848689704`,44.91040965366457`,18.41061541949269`} *)
```